# Как править раздел справки?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Читая разные темы в разделе справки, я сталкиваюсь с большим количеством стилистических ошибок. Поэтому хочу узнать: возможно ли править их или кто-то планирует заняться приведением их в порядок? Как-то странно это видеть на таком сайте, для которого грамотность стоит на одном из ведущих мест. Я думаю, все согласны, что читать написанное таким языком не очень приятно, хоть и понимаешь смысл и неоднозначности толкования не возникает.

Answer (score 3):

Да, возможно. Наилучший, на мой взгляд, вариант – переписать все, что не нравится. Для этого, задайте вопрос на Мете, указав ссылку на исходный вариант и ниже ваш вариант текста.

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, [как это происходит на Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373/). Также, вы можете сделать вопрос «общим», чтобы другие участники сообщества тоже могли принять участие в улучшении публикации.

Comment: Спасибо, Nicolas!